# Find max value in an array only with if else condition

Tags: c#

I am a very beginner in c#. How to find the maximum value in an array only with if else conditions?

```
int max = 0;
```

Comment: Is this a class assignment? If it is, tell your teacher from me that it's the most nonsensic assignment ever, that code screams asking for a loop... xD

Answer (score 1):

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] x = new int[3];
x[0] = random.Next(200);
x[1] = random.Next(200);
x[2] = random.Next(200);
int max = x[0];

if (max < x[1]) max = x[1];
if (max < x[2]) max = x[2];
// Now you have max.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int max = x[0];

if (x[1] > max)
    max = x[1];
if (x[2] > max)
    max = x[2];

// Use max here.
```

Or the long way:

```
if (x[0] > x[1])
{
    if (x[2] > x[0])
        max = x[2];
    else
        max = x[0];
}
else
{
    if (x[2] > x[1])
        max = x[2];
    else
        max = x[1];
}

// Use max here.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is **more optimal** and will find the maximum amount:

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] x = new int[3];
x[0] = random.Next(200);
x[1] = random.Next(200);
x[2] = random.Next(200);

int max = x[0];

if (x[1] > max)
    max = x[1];
if (x[2] > max)
    max = x[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Yes it's possible, have a look at the following logic.
// let's have x[0] = 5, x[1] = 10, x[2] = 15

if (x[0] > x[1]) //  5 > 10 false
{
   if (x[0] > x[2]) Console.WriteLine("Number one is the largest!\n");
   else Console.WriteLine("Number three is the largest!\n");
}
else if (x[1] > x[2]) // 10 > 15 false
     Console.WriteLine("Number two is the largest!\n"); 
else Console.WriteLine("Number three is the largest!\n"); // 15 is the biggest.
```

// Try any combination out it should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] values = new int[]{1,30,3,4,8};
        Console.WriteLine(GetMax(values));
    }
    
    public static int GetMax(int[] values, int index = 0)
    {
        if(values.Length > index + 1)
        {
            int maxFromRest = GetMax(values, index + 1);
            return values[index] > maxFromRest ? values[index]: maxFromRest;
        }
        else 
        {
            return values[index];
        }
    }
}
```